# Consolidate table using soundex

Tags: soundex

I have a massive table of similar sounding entries(around 500) and the order numbers next to them: eg.

Benzin 3000,
Ben 209,
benziloate 800,
.
.
.
Cret 20,
cretis 333,

etc.

please note that the first 3 letters are not always the same but the names are similar sounding.
I have been trying to figure out a system to find all the similar sounding entries, collate them all into 1 and add up the values of their orders.
I have tried Soundex as that searches by similar sounding letters, however I have not been able to modify it so that it includes more than one entry and includes the sum of the orders next to it.

Does anyone have any suggestions of an easier way of doing this?
thank you very much in advance